css scoping, surround css file so it only applies to inside a specific selector
I have a CSS file
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .w-tc-editor {
    --color-fg-default: #c9d1d9;
    --color-canvas-subtle: #161b22;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-comment: #8b949e;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-entity-tag: #7ee787;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-entity: #d2a8ff;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-sublimelinter-gutter-mark: #484f58;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-constant: #79c0ff;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-string: #a5d6ff;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-keyword: #ff7b72;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-markup-bold: #c9d1d9;
  }
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  .w-tc-editor {
    --color-fg-default: #24292f;
    --color-canvas-subtle: #f6f8fa;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-comment: #6e7781;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-entity-tag: #116329;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-entity: #8250df;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-sublimelinter-gutter-mark: #8c959f;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-constant: #0550ae;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-string: #0a3069;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-keyword: #cf222e;
    --color-prettylights-syntax-markup-bold: #24292f;
  }
}
.w-tc-editor[data-color-mode*='dark'],
[data-color-mode*='dark'] .w-tc-editor,
[data-color-mode*='dark'] .w-tc-editor-var,
body[data-color-mode*='dark'] {
  --color-fg-default: #c9d1d9;
  --color-canvas-subtle: #161b22;
  --color-prettylights-syntax-comment: #8b949e;
  --color-prettylights-syntax-entity-tag: #7ee787;
  --color-prettylights-syntax-entity: #d2a8ff;
  --color-prettylights-syntax-sublimelinter-gutter-mark: #484f58;
  --color-prettylights-syntax-constant: #79c0ff;
  --color-prettylights-syntax-string: #a5d6ff;
  --color-prettylights-syntax-keyword: #ff7b72;
  --color-prettylights-syntax-markup-bold: #c9d1d9;
}

and so on....
I have the contents of this file as a string and i need a way to transform the text in a way that all these rules, only apply for elements inside a specific element....
Ideally, with css nesting would be as simple as
const scopedCssText = `#my-container { ${cssText} }`;

but this isn't working.
Whatever solution would be awesome, as long as it works
I tried asking copilot for a regex to try to include
#my-container >  before every selector but of course it didn't work
My end goal is loading a compiled react app, through an extension, on a site (that i don't want to mess up with this css)
I'm running, from the extension:
 chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        func: () => {
          let wrapper = document.getElementById('pertento-editor-wrapper');
          if (!wrapper) {
            wrapper = document.createElement('div');
            wrapper.id = 'pertento-editor-wrapper';
            wrapper.style.position = 'fixed';
            wrapper.style.top = 0;
            wrapper.style.left = 0;
            wrapper.style.width = '100%';
            wrapper.style.height = '100%';
            wrapper.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
            wrapper.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = 'http://localhost:3000/editor.js';
            const link = document.createElement('link');
            link.rel = 'stylesheet';
            link.href = 'http://localhost:3000/editor.css';
            document.head.appendChild(link);
            document.body.appendChild(script);
          }
        },
      });

Much appreciated

Not sure what could be the problem with nesting not working, maybe the css contains rules that cannot be nested.
Have you thought about using ShadowDOM to encapsulate the CSS within the wrapper?

looking into it now

I need to learn better about shadow dom, i've tried several ways from mdn and i can't make it work, righ now. Tomorrow try again. Thanks

Original Solution: non relevant.
Rename the css file to scss or less, wrap it inside your outer selector, and compile using your IDE or online.
Example:
#my-container {

    /* your original css */

}

Solution 2:
We'll use a javascript less compiler.


var css = `
  @media (prefers-color-scheme:dark) {
    h1 {
      color: blue;
    }
  }

  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
`

var lessInput = `
  .my-container {
    ${css}
  }
`

function addStyle(css) {
  const style = document.createElement('style');
  style.textContent = css
  document.head.appendChild(style)
}

less.render(lessInput)
  .then(function(output) {
    // console.log(output.css)
    addStyle(output.css)
  });
.my-container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/4.2.0/less.js"></script>
<h1>H1 - regular</h1>

<div class="my-container">
  <h1>H1 - scoped</h1>
</div>




so close!
The problem is, the contents inside my container are still affected by the overall styles and i can't seem to get the shadowdom to work

but this has already been a great help and i think i'm going to mark it as the correct answer as my subsequent problems are not directly related to this question

thanks, but if isolation to shadow dom will be the answer, then i'll settle for an "up vote" instead

no worries, your answer covered my question perfectly. I ended up not using it though, i completely remade my code to use an iframe instead of this whole mess :)
